# Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process [Android] [Gradle]

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, flutter

Whenever trying to run a flutter app I am greeted with this error.

`* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: D:\Projects\buisnesscard\build\app\intermediates\transforms\mergeJavaRes\debug\0.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

I tried adding:

`packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }`

to my build gradle file and restarting android studio however the error still occurs.

My /app/build.gradle looks like this:

`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.seandiacono.buisnesscard"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

`

Answer (score 7):

What works for me is to close Android Studio, go to my workspace in the File Explorer and delete {project}/app/build. Then reopen Android Studio.

Comment: Ran across something similar in Expo, also worked here.

Answer (score 3):

I added

```
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/*'
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
    }
```

in the android portion of my app/build.gradle file, and then I went into FileExplorer [myproject]/app and deleted the entire directory titled "build"

Answer (score 2):

Try this 
 Android studio :

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.. > Invalidate/ Restart
```

or terminal:

```
flutter clean
```

Comment: I tried `flutter clean` but I got error `'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 1):

Possible issue: the problem is that the Java service/process gets stuck with the file in your debug folder (that why the error message point to your .jar file),

Possible solution: you have to restart or kill the Java service/process.

With that I was able to solve the problem, I hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

**For them, who tried everything**

I faced the same issue and there were a lot of stuffs as a solution, mostly flutter clean and stopping java.exe. But what I found in the end is,

When I run my app my storage reaches it's max. And then the program ends up doing this. So for me none of those solution worked. I just had to figure it out and clear my storage a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same issue when started updating my project from windows. Same project works fine and able to build apk in mac os.

In my case the issue was due to heap analytics. If you don't want to use heap analytics disable heap in build.gradle and remove related dependencies.
Or if it was a requirement, please go through my solution below.

Current System OS : Windows 10

---

> My solution :
>
> 1. Updated all dependencies with latest version (only updating lib doesn't resolve the issue: but its recommended).
> 2. Update `'com.heapanalytics.android'` version (**very important) in project level `build.gradle`. In my case I updated to version '1.7.0'
> 3. Update google play services version in project level `build.gradle`
> 4. Add `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` permisiion in manifest if not previously included. It was for
>    firebase analytics instance.

---

Invalidate caches and restart, then Rebuild your project.

**`Nb: It will be helpful if anyone struggling with same scenario. That's why i'm posting here. Thanks.`**

Answer (score 0):

Moving my folder out of my **Dropbox** folder and doing a `flutter clean` fixed something similar for me.

Answer (score 0):

This always works for me on Windows. Open Task Manager, go to Details tab, find and kill java.exe and run app again.